# Counting circles using morphological operations

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-morphology

I had an image, in which I was asked to count the number of circles. I was able to reduce it down to this image:

[image]

Now I can use the number of connected components to get the answer. That's okay. But is it possible to do this using only morphological operations? (like somehow getting the "center" of these "circles" and then simply counting the pixels)

Comment: You can get the contours and count the contour. I do not see how you can do the counting with morphology alone. If you know the area of one circle in pixels, then you can simply count the white pixels and divide by the area of one circle.

Comment: In Matlab is function: bwmorph(Image, 'shrink', Inf)

Comment: @AlexAlex I'm using python

Comment: thinning is implemented in OpenCV python, see here:
https://answers.opencv.org/question/163561/looking-for-a-thinningskeletonizing-algorithm-with-opencv-in-python/

Comment: Why do you not want to use connected components to count the circles though? It is quite fast, probably a lot faster than to compute the image skeleton and count the white pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an operation called thinning, which iteratively erodes the image but retains a specific set of points (it's a conditional erosion). Depending on the set of structuring elements used in the conditional erosion, the operation can reduce objects to a single point (or a circle for objects with a hole in them). You could apply with a thinning and then count pixels.

As Alex Alex mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61278429/counting-circles-using-morphological-operations#comment108405851_61278429), in MATLAB `bwmorph(Image, 'shrink', Inf)` performs this operation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best and fastest method is `cv2.findcontours()`.